# How to store the previous value of a user while its in a loop?

Tags: java, variables, while-loop

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Hello {

    public static int s1;
    public static int newvalue;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        userInputAndPrimeNumber();
        calculate();

    }

    public static void userInputAndPrimeNumber() {
        newvalue = 0;

        do {
            String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer. Enter 0 to quit. ");

            s1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);

            if (s1 == 0)
                break;



            if (s1 > newvalue) {
                newvalue = s1;
            }

        } while (s1 > 0);

    }

    public static void calculate() {

        System.out.println("The greatest positive number is: " + newvalue);

    }
}
```

I would like to find the least, greatest, average, and the number of inputs the user has given (without using arrays). In the above code, I have figured out a way to store the greatest value. I'm having a hard time to figure out the remaining because I'm not able to store the previous values which the user types in?

Answer (score 0):

You can have some variables to store the least and the greatest as well as to count the number of inputs (called by **count**) and the sum of the inputs (called by **sum**). After that, you can calculate the average based on the sum and the count. For the least, you can do as the way you calculate the greatest. Hope it helpful!

Comment: Could you please tell what is the value to be assigned to the variables?

Comment: For the least variables, you can initialize with the very large integer number, may be 999999 depends on your needs; for the greatest, just do as you did but the conditions should be "greater than equal" and "less than equal". For the sum and the count, just set both it as 0 at beginning and plus itself after each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need 4 variables and call the code behind it after every run:
runs: `runs++;`
greatest: -> `if (s1 > greatest) greatest = s1;`
smallest: `if(s1 < smallest) smallest = s1;`
average: `average+= s1;`
And at the end:`average = average / runs;`

Comment: if we initialize greatest and smallest to 0 the smallest: if(s1 > smallest) will be false right? what do we initialize it to?

Comment: could you please elaborate the answer as to what should be assigned to the variables?

Comment: initialize with "null" and set the first Value you get. There are two ways for this put the first request outside the loop or make a nullCheck after every request.